# Is there a way to verify the integrity of a rsnapshot backups?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, rsync

I'm using rsnapshot to make daily backups to a second hdd.
But how can I make sure, that no file in my backup is corrupted?

If I use the checksum option from rsync, the whole backup will take much longer, but files with errors on the second hdd will be transferred again. 
But if the file is corrupted on the main hdd, the error will creepy into the backups.

So is there a way to monitor the state of the backup in respect to the original file (and even vice versa?) and get a warning, if a file content got corrupted?